# fadeOut then fadeIn sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

I'm trying to fade out one image, then fade in another image in the same spot.

So far I've got this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mraxlee/bmu43fm7/8/), but you can see it changes the image before the `.fadeOut()` function finishes, when changing image via clicking thumbs. I've read that jQuery doesn't run sequentially as standard (which my code is assuming it does), so I tried adding in the completed function, like so:

```
$('#image').fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $('#image').html('<a href="' + image + '" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="' + title + '"><img src="' + image + '" class="image"/></a>');
    $('#image').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

However my issue is still present. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Is the issue when clicking thumbnails?

Comment: @MrAxlee The fiddle you've linked is out of date.

Comment: I pasted the code from your question into your fiddle and it seemed to work. I don't see any flickering. Could you update your fiddle to include your latest code?

Comment: @JosephMarikle I've updated the code to the latest version, but the issue is still present for me.

Comment: Is expected result that `#slider` not fade to appearance of empty background during image transitions ?

Comment: @guest271314 Fades to either white, ready for the new image to fade in, or a crossfade - either would be acceptable

Comment: The updated fiddle has the image changing during the fade because you have the `...html(...)` line twice, once in the complete callback and once outside it. Delete the second one and it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/bmu43fm7/11/

Comment: @MrAxlee See post. Approach sets `background-color` to `#000` - same as images - to mask any flicker between image transitions.

Comment: @nnnnnn your fix worked perfectly, thank you! What a silly blunder I made, I spent a good 2 hours trying to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't destroy and recreate the elements; I'd just update the attributes. I'd also include a `.stop(true, true)` to cancel any previous animation and jump straight to the end before starting the fadeout, in case someone clicks quickly.

```js
var images = [
  'https://i.stack.imgur.com/uClcV.jpg?s=328&g=1',
  'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d050da3cf82fdf6cfa431358fee9a397?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1',
  'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG'
];
var current = 0;
updateImage(images[current], images[current]);

function updateImage(image, title) {
  var img = $('#image');
  img.stop(true, true).fadeOut('fast', function() {
    img.find('a').attr('href', image).attr('title', title);
    img.find('img').attr('src', image);
    img.fadeIn('fast');
  });
}

$("#next").click(function() {
  current = (current + 1) % images.length;
  updateImage(images[current], images[current]);
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="next" value="Next">
<div id="image">
  <a>
    <img style="height: 128px; width: 128px"><!-- Never do that, but for a demo, it's okay -->
  </a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is an important thing to note.

Comment: What if the image takes a while to download?

Comment: @lbstr: I'd make a point of preloading them so they were in cache.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yep good call. I wanted to call this out for readers because if you fade in for 200ms and the image takes 300ms, you'll likely just see the image flash in. If preloading isn't an option, you might try to bind a load callback. +1

Answer (score 0):

> Is expected result that #slider not fade to appearance of empty
>   background during image transitions ?

---

> Fades to either white, ready for the new image to fade in, or a crossfade - either would be acceptable

---

Try setting `#slider` `width` , `height` to expected `img` width, height; setting `background-color` to `#000`

css

```
#slider {
    width:500px;
    height:505px;
    background-color:#000;    
}
```

js

```
//clicking thumbnails
$(".image").click(function () {
    var image = $(this).attr("rel"); //getting the rel tag from the a tag
    var title = $(this).attr("data-title"); //data title from a tag
    $('#image').fadeOut('fast', function() { //fades out last image
    $('#image').html('<a href="' + image + '" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="' + title + '">'
    + '<img src="' + image + '" class="image"/></a>')
    .fadeIn('fast'); 
    })
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bmu43fm7/13/

Comment: Your demo (version 12 of the fiddle) still has the same problem as the OP described. That is, the image changes *before* the fade out is complete.